# Is that possible to create a LAN messenger ( with user verification ) without a central server..?

Tags: java, lan

Is that possible to create a LAN messenger ( with user verification ) without a central server..?

I want to use JAVA for the messenger and with the facility of video conference. The main problem I faced is that how/where will I save user's data.

Answer (score 0):

You can save data locally on each machine.

Answer (score 0):

If by without a server you mean without any central computer then yes you can (with any computer listening and dynamically taking server role or something like everyone is server and client simultanously). It could work like p2p.

You could also use brodcast messages to achieve that. User authentication is the issue, but you can store user id's and hashed passwords on each machine (and syncronizing it as often as possible)

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented it some years ago: basically I do a listen on an UDP port for each time a user open his client (I've done that by a separate thread) that accept a particular type of pkt that define username, user ip and so on...
In that way i have a kind of p2p mechanism.

User auth is achived by store user's password in a crypted way (sha5 and so on..)

Comment: can you send me your project.

Comment: Sorry but I can't because was a school project (4-5 years ago) that "died" with my old notebook :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some DHT as an underlying system. It should be able handle all communications between the network nodes as well as distributed data storage.
A new node can join if it knows at least one node that is already in the network. And a node can send a message to some other node if it knows its ip or dns name.

P.S.: If you're interested in the idea you may took a look on [Open Chord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-chord/). Its only drawback is that there's no persistence, i.e. it doesn't store the data anywhere except the RAM, so you'll need to add your own persistence.

P.P.S.: you may event create new skype but without a central server at all